# How to fix Bootstrap error when I run webpack-dev-server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bootstrap-loader

When I run `npm start` script command for webpack-dev-server in the console, the `localhost:8080` opens in the browser but doesn'render my ./src/index.js file. Instead I get an error pointing to a bootstrap file.

**My project's tree**

```
My Project
    /node_modules
    /src
        /components
            Counter.js
        index.html
        index.css
        index.js
    package.json
    package-lock.json
    webpack.config.js
```

**Package.json**

```
{
"name": "react_project", 
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.28.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            '@babel/preset-react'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'html-loader' }]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

**./src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Counter from './components/Counter';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**.src/index.html**

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

**.src/components/Counter.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

**This is how the error looks in the terminal**

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in 'C:\Users\cristi\WORK\My Project\src'
 @ ./src/index.js 4:0-24
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8084 ./src

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Counter' in 'C:\Users\cristi\WORK\My Project\src'
 @ ./src/index.js 6:0-43 7:36-43
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8084 ./src

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/index.css' in 'C:\Users\cristi\WORK\My Project\src'
 @ ./src/index.js 3:0-25
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8084 ./src

ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 7:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
|  */
> :root {
|   --blue: #007bff;
|   --indigo: #6610f2;
 @ ./src/index.js 5:0-42
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8084 ./src
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html] 359 bytes {0} [built]
i ?wdm?: Failed to compile.
```

**GitHub project's files if you want to try them out**

https://github.com/cristiAndreiTarasi/FStackoverflow

I want to get `webpack` to work properly with `bootstrap` and create the `./dist` folder in order to get the result in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `./src/index.js` you import `App`:

```js
import App from './App';
```

But you 1) don't use `App` and also there is no `App.js(x)` in your project directory. Remove that line or comment it out (since you're not using it).

Then for the error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Counter'`:

You say in your question that your project directory looks like:

```
My Project
    /src
        /component
            Counter.js
```

But your GitHub shows that `Counter.js` actually is [`Counter.jsx`](https://github.com/cristiAndreiTarasi/FStackoverflow/tree/master/src/components). If you want to import files without extensions (`'./Counter'` instead of `./Counter.jsx` or `./Counter.js`), Webpack - without any tweaking - [defaults to one of](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions): `['.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.json']`.  You need to add the following to your webpack config if you want also want to import `.jsx` without extension:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.jsx'] // add .jsx
  }
};
```

For the error `Error: Can't resolve './src/index.css'`: once again, your GitHub doesn't show an `index.css` file in your `src` directory.

You also need [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) set up to solve the following error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 7:0 Module
>   parse failed: Unexpected token (7:0)

The errors you receive are actually very descriptive.